# How do I insertion sort a list of lists?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-3.x, insertion-sort

```
def insertionSort(mylist):
for index in range(1, len(mylist)):
    currentvalue = mylist[index]
    position = index
    while position > 0 and mylist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
        mylist[position] = mylist[position - 1]
        position = position - 1
    mylist[position] = currentvalue
return mylist
```

Above I have some code which can insertion sort a list of lists, for example

```
list1 = [(12,45,62),(78,35,72),(34,52,75)]
insertionSort(list1)
```

yields

```
list1 = [(12,45,62),(34,52,75),(78,35,72)]
```

Which sorts each sub-list by the first element (12, 34 and 78). How can I make the insertion sort sort by the second and third elements of the sub-lists?

Comment: Is there a reason why you insist on using insertion sort?

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre Does it matter, in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting functions in the Python library provide a `key` parameter for this purpose, determining the function used to get the key for comparing two elements. You can do the same for your own insertion sort. The default value for this parameter could be a function returning the element itself, but it can be overridden with any other key function.

```
def insertionSort(mylist, key=lambda x: x):
    for index in range(1, len(mylist)):
        currentvalue = mylist[index]
        position = index
        while position > 0 and key(mylist[position - 1]) > key(currentvalue):
            mylist[position] = mylist[position - 1]
            position = position - 1
        mylist[position] = currentvalue
    return mylist
```

Examples:

```
>>> list1 = [(12,45,62),(78,35,72),(34,52,75)]
>>> insertionSort(list1)
[(12, 45, 62), (34, 52, 75), (78, 35, 72)]
>>> insertionSort(list1, key=lambda x: x[1])
[(78, 35, 72), (12, 45, 62), (34, 52, 75)]
```

Note: In `sort` and `sorted`, the `key` function will be evaluated only once for each value in the list, whereas in this version, it is evaluated for every comparison. If you want to call the function just once, you could, e.g., cache the key values in a dictionary.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for your answer