# Sorting a 2D array using insertion sort algorithm

Tags: python

I have the following code in which I am trying to implement insertion sort but only able to sort the Names but not the numbers. What I should do so it will sort the numbers as well with their names.

```
def insertionsort(searchList):
  for index in range(1,len(searchList)):
    #Name
    currentValue1 = searchList[index][0]
    #mark1
    currentValue2 = searchList[index][1]
    #mark2
    currentValue3 = searchList[index][2]

    #store the position to be shifted to
    position = index

    while position > 0 and searchList[position-1][0] > currentValue1[0]:
      searchList[position][0] = searchList[position-1][0]
      searchList[position][1] = searchList[position-1][1]
      searchList[position][2] = searchList[position-1][2]
      position = position - 1

    #store the value to be inserted into the array
    searchList[position][0] = currentValue1
    searchList[position][1] = currentValue2
    searchList[position][2] = currentValue3

  return searchList

list = [["John",23,18],
        ["Aaron",11,10],
        ["Brad",22,11]
       ]
         
print(insertionsort(list))
```

**Current Output**

```
[['Aaron', 11, 10], ['Brad', 22, 11], ['John', 23, 18]]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[['Aaron', 10, 11], ['Brad', 11, 22], ['John', 18, 23]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you got your code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36864009/15521392) ?

I made some smaller changes to make your code a bit easier to read.

- First, you can use tuple unpacking, that way it looks cleaner than your multiple lines accessing each position of the list one by one.
- If you just compare the list with the first element and change the order of the whole list, you can swap them all together instead of each element at a time.
- At the end you just check whether mark1 is smaller than mark2 or not
  and store the value accordingly.
- Also you need to start at index 0 so every list in your list of lists
  gets checked.
- You shoudn't name your list `list`, name it `my_list` or something
  else. `list` is a python build-in function and shouldn't be a name of
  your variable.

```
def insertionsort(searchList: list) -> list:
    for index in range(0,len(searchList)):
        #Name, mark1, mark2
        name, mark1, mark2 = searchList[index]

        #store the position to be shifted to
        position = index

        while position > 0 and searchList[position-1][0] > name[0]:
            searchList[position] = searchList[position-1]
            position -= 1

        #store the value to be inserted into the array
        if mark1 < mark2:
            searchList[position] = [name, mark1, mark2]
        else:
            searchList[position] = [name, mark2, mark1]
    
    return searchList

lst = [["John",23,18],
        ["Aaron",11,10],
        ["Brad",22,11]
       ]
         
print(insertionsort(lst))

[['Aaron', 10, 11], ['Brad', 11, 22], ['John', 18, 23]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def insertionsort(searchList):
  for index in range(len(searchList)): # start the for loop with the index '0' instead of '1', to incorporate all the values.
    #Name
    currentValue1 = searchList[index][0]
    #mark1
    currentValue2 = searchList[index][1]
    #mark2
    currentValue3 = searchList[index][2]

    #store the position to be shifted to
    position = index

    while position > 0 and searchList[position-1][0] > currentValue1[0]:
      searchList[position][0] = searchList[position-1][0]
      searchList[position][1] = searchList[position-1][1]
      searchList[position][2] = searchList[position-1][2]
      position = position - 1

    #store the value to be inserted into the array
    searchList[position][0] = currentValue1

    # find the smaller and bigger value amongst the two values
    min_val = min(currentValue2, currentValue3)
    max_val = max(currentValue2, currentValue3)

    # add the smaller and bigger values in the sorted order
    searchList[position][1] = min_val
    searchList[position][2] = max_val

  return searchList

list = [["John",23,18],
        ["Aaron",11,10],
        ["Brad",22,11]
       ]
         
print(insertionsort(list))
```